# How can i find a transaction in paypal which is not made via rest api?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am not able to find payment or sale object in paypal with the txn_id returned in IPN message. I want to process refund via rest api call for such transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can perform a refund via REST API call only if your transaction was made via REST. Anyway, it depend of the flow that the transaction followed...

If you want provide further details, I will be more than happy to provide more information about.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd love to hear more details about this. I'm working on an app that currently uses the "classic" api to make payments. We're looking to migrate to the REST api. Is it possible to make a refund using the REST api using a transaction id that was created with the classic API? Is there any way to translate a classic transaction_id into a sale id that the REST api can use and understand? Thanks.